# Are there any platform agnostic ways to schedule tasks using PHP?

Tags: php, operating-system, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm currently looking for a way that I can build a scheduling system that could run scripts at a certain date and/or time, and do it in such a way that it doesn't care what operating system it's living on. I know with linux/unix, I can add enteries using cron, but with other OS's? NOt so much.

Also if there's a way to have it execute without relying on external software such as cron, I'd be interested to learn about those options as well, although I realize that's probably a stretch with PHP.

Thanks for your help in this matter!

Comment: hosting php on anything but  *nix is non optimal

Comment: @dagon agreed. Sadly convincing potential clients to switch architectures usually kills off any potential adoption of an application.

Comment: I like writing SAAS apps, I dictate the hosting environment

Comment: Have you considered online scheduling services such as scheduler.codeeffects.com or wsscheduler.com? Bunch of them are free and reliable.

Comment: @kizz I have not, but it would at least remove the platform side of things. I'll give them a looksee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write a persistent server in PHP that runs 24 hours a day, then scheduling tasks is easy; loop forever and check if there are any tasks scheduled for the current time each second and run them... run the code or spawn a process to do so with `exec`.

Assuming you did not intend to write a persistent server in PHP, then no, there's no platform agnostic way to schedule tasks with the operating system.

Comment: php daemons, functional but problematic

Comment: Indeed. I've actually never looked into that side of PHP before, was always taught that if you are getting into things that require exec(), it's time to look at a language that operates closer to the hardware level then PHP does.

Comment: i agree but optimal coding often clashes with business expedience.